# Unable to install bundle

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler

I'm following the instruction on the [Rails Tutorial Chapter 3](http://www.railstutorial.org/book). When running the command line `bundle install --without production` I'm getting:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "sprockets-rails":

In snapshot (Gemfile.lock):
  sprockets-rails (2.1.3)

In Gemfile:

sass-rails (= 4.0.1) ruby depends on
  sprockets-rails (~> 2.0.0) ruby
```

Running `bundle update` will rebuild your snapshot from scratch, using only
the gems in your Gemfile, which may resolve the conflict.

When running bundle update I'm getting:

```
An error occurred while installing nokogiri (1.6.2.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.2.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

When I run `gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.2.1'` it complains:

> Building native extensions. This could take a while... Building
>   nokogiri using packaged libraries. ERROR: Error installing nokogiri:
>   ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
>   /Users/yotamros/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin/ruby extconf.rb Building
>   nokogiri using packaged libraries. ----- libiconv is missing. please
>   visit nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html for help with
>   installing dependencies. ----- *** extconf.rb failed ***

This is my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.1.2'
#ruby-gemset=railstutorial_rails_4_0

gem 'rails', '4.1.1'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.8'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.13.1'
end

group :test do
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.35.1'
  gem 'capybara', '2.1.0'
end

gem 'sass-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'uglifier', '2.1.1'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'jquery-rails', '3.0.4'
gem 'turbolinks', '1.1.1'
gem 'jbuilder', '1.0.2'

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', '0.3.20', require: false
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.15.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Try running `gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.2.1'` and tell us what error you get?

Comment: Here is the error:  Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Building nokogiri using packaged libraries.
ERROR:  Error installing nokogiri:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/yotamros/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin/ruby extconf.rb
Building nokogiri using packaged libraries.
-----
libiconv is missing.  please visit http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html for help with installing dependencies.
-----
*** extconf.rb failed ***

Comment: What is your Operating System?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution that worked for me [here](https://www.bountysource.com/issues/2293997-nokogiri-error-libiconv-missing-on-mavericks) (by Claudio Poli):

1. `brew reinstall libiconv libxml2 libxslt`
2. `gem install nokogiri -- --with-iconv-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/libiconv/1.14/`

Answer (score 0):

Try bumping `sass-rails to '~> 4.0.3'` in your Gemfile. You have it locked to a specific slightly out of date version. For what it's worth, a brand new Rails 4.1.1 project has these gems:

```
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
```

(I would have put this in a comment but I'm not that cool yet.)

Comment: I changed sass-rails to 4.0.3 in the Gemfile.  I'm getting this error when running bundle install --without production: An error occurred while installing nokogiri (1.6.2.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.2.1'` succeeds before bundling.

Comment: See "install libiconv from source" on this page:

http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html

Might help. I've used nokigiri on 10.9.3 without having to install libiconv though, so I'm not sure why some people have to.